# how to check the value of a Asp.Net textbox

Tags: asp.net, validation, web

I have to check dynamically if the value written inside a textbox like:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="id" name="id" type="text" 
size="50" Style="height: 22px; text-align: left;" 
MaxLength="100" runat="server" />
```

have a length equal to 10 characters.

I want to show to the user an error alert like a balloon o a little sign near the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RegularExpressionValidator` for this. Put this code next to your `TextBox`:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
    runat="server" ErrorMessage="ID must be 10 characters long" 
    ControlToValidate="id" ValidationExpression=".{10}">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

use Range Validators and specify Min and Max range

```
<asp:RangeValidator ControlToValidate="id" MinimumValue="10" MaximumValue="100" Type="Integer" EnableClientScript="false" Text="must be between 10 and 100!" runat="server" />
```

or else you can use jquery:

```
  $('#ID').blur(function () {
                var textval = ('#ID').val()
                if(textval.length==4)
                {
                  //Code to display enter code here your custom popup 
                }
            });
```